# How to get specific path for Linux system

Tags: php, linux

I have developed the code on windows machine so the code is below

```php
if (!file_exists('C:/xampp/htdocs/Collector/config_manifest.ini')){
   $ec->writeErrorMessage("manifest config file not found");
   exit; 
}
```

The code moved to Linux system and path which i found via FTP is `/var/www/html/php/Collector/config_manifest.in` now how to write this in `file_exists` in PHP to know that file exist or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`__DIR__`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant. Big upside is that this constant is OS-independent so it works on Linux, Window, macOS, and pretty much any other thing that runs PHP.

```
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/config_manifest.ini')
```

Comment: DO i not need to put var/www/html/php/collector ?

Comment: Nope, it's a relative file path. https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-and-relative-paths-3466467

Comment: Ok but somewhere i have code like this $info_array = parse_ini_file('C:/xampp/htdocs/Collector/config_manifest.ini', true); $info_array = parse_ini_file('C:/xampp/htdocs/Collector/config_manifest.ini', true); how to to change these ?

Comment: With the keyboard. Look up what file you make these statements and change them just the way I did in my answer. Probably along the lines of `__DIR__ . '/Collector/config_manifest.ini'`

Answer (score 2):

You just put the new path where the old path was.

```
if (!file_exists('/var/www/html/php/Collector/config_manifest.in'))
```

Comment: Like in C it starting from C:/xamp so do you think if i put from var/www it will work ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma — It starts from `/`!